# Spring Cloud DataFlow Server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm studying and doing some POC's with Spring Cloud DataFlow and I'm having some problems:

I am trying to start a Local Data Flow Server. In order to achieve this, I just created an Spring Boot Application and annotate this with `@EnableDataFlowServer`.

When I try to run, i get the following error:

```
11:54:53.307 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.context.logging.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener - Application failed to start with classpath: 
[...]
11:54:53.395 [background-preinit] INFO org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.0.13.Final
11:54:53.406 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.TraversableResolvers - Found javax.persistence.Persistence on classpath containing 'getPersistenceUtil'. Assuming JPA 2 environment. Trying to instantiate JPA aware TraversableResolver
11:54:53.408 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.TraversableResolvers - Instantiated JPA aware TraversableResolver of type org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.
11:54:53.413 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.config.ValidationXmlParser - Trying to load META-INF/validation.xml for XML based Validator configuration.
11:54:53.414 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.config.ResourceLoaderHelper - Trying to load META-INF/validation.xml via TCCL
11:54:53.414 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.config.ResourceLoaderHelper - Trying to load META-INF/validation.xml via Hibernate Validator's class loader
11:54:53.415 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.config.ValidationXmlParser - No META-INF/validation.xml found. Using annotation based configuration only.
11:54:53.590 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator - Loaded expression factory via original TCCL
11:54:53.596 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator as ValidatorFactory-scoped message interpolator.
11:54:53.597 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver as ValidatorFactory-scoped traversable resolver.
11:54:53.597 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.ExecutableParameterNameProvider as ValidatorFactory-scoped parameter name provider.
11:54:53.597 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.DefaultClockProvider as ValidatorFactory-scoped clock provider.
11:54:53.597 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.scripting.DefaultScriptEvaluatorFactory as ValidatorFactory-scoped script evaluator factory.
11:54:53.866 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.([Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:161)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:102)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:68)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:74)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:338)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:297)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1242)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1230)
    at com.arrobaautowired.springclouddataflowserver.SpringCloudDataflowServerApplication.main(SpringCloudDataflowServerApplication.java:12)
```

I was looking for help and I readed that it could be a pom's version problem. Actually my `pom.xml` is:

```
<-- [...] --> 

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- DataFlow Server -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local-autoconfig</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're creating a Boot App from scratch? Curious to understand why you cannot use the binary directly that we ship (see [here](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/#platform-implementations)).

Comment: When I started studying Spring Cloud, the tutorial I followed suggested doing so. Now I have used the binary but I would like to know why this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the update in the comments.

We used to promote the SCDF customization model in the past, but we have decided to move out of it for a variety of reasons, so that is why it is not mentioned in the docs. Hence, we removed it from Spring Initializr, too.

As for the error, it appears you're on Boot 2.x line, but SCDF is still on 1.5.x baseline. You could switch to Boot 1.5.17 and retry.

Also, as an FYI, SCDF's baseline is switching to Boot 2.1 in the coming weeks.